# addTagHelper in component document

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

So Im fairly new to Blazor and .Net Core and Im trying to include a custom TagHelper inside my MainLayout.razor like so:

```
@addTagHelper *, SmartBreadcrumbs
```

Inside the _Host file it works as expected, but in any other file Im getting:

The directives @addTagHelper, @removeTagHelper and @tagHelperPrefix are not valid in a component document. Use '@using ' directive instead.

Im not sure what Im missing in order to be able to use the tag  inside other files then the _Host.cshtml.

Link to what Im implementing https://github.com/zHaytam/SmartBreadcrumbs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use Html tag Helpers in a Blazor app. There is no such thing.

Note: The _Host.cshtml file is a Razor Pages page, not a Razor Component page. Html tag Helpers can be used in Razor Pages App's pages. Thus you can use Html tag Helpers in the _Host.cshtml file. The component tag helper is used in the _Host.cshtml file to instantiate the Blazor SPA.

```
<component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
```

Note: SmartBreadcrumbs is written for MVC and Razor Pages Apps, not Blazor. Search for SmartBreadcrumbs implemented with Blazor.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! I was mixing what a Razor Page is with Razor Component page..